# iOS Cannot SIGINT or Ctrl+C when SSH'ed into it

Tags: ios, bash, jailbreak, ssh, cydia

I have a jailbroken iPhone that I often SSH into. For some reason, I am unable to Ctrl+C a foreground process or `kill -INT` a background process when said process is started in an SSH session, but I *can* when it's started from the on-board terminal (NewTerm2, installed via Cydia). Each time I want to start a process that I might want to interrupt, I've got to either physically do it on the on-board terminal, or start it from SSH, but need to `SIGKILL` it, as it oddly ignores `SIGINT`/Ctrl+C. Why might this happen?